# Search in hibernate over collection very slow

Tags: hibernate, search

I have class which has some fields and one of them is Collection of child. Problem is that child make class unique and I must search duplicates by child (from beginning class does not has any ID).

So I write smth like this:

```
SELECT c
FROM Class c, IN(c.children) c1, IN(c.children) c2, IN(c.children) c3
WHERE c.project='project' AND c1.name='name1' AND c2.name='name2' AND c3.name='name3'
```

it works fine while You have more or less unique c.project.
but in some case I must import large amount of data with same project (or null) and then search can take 5-6 seconds on 200-300 c with 3-4 children.

I missing something big I suppose but dont know what exactly. Can You please help me.

UPDATE:
This query can give me clue if I already have such object in database and dont need to add one more (as I say - no ID from beginning).
I mean - if in database exist object with same project(project!=ID) and same set of children than I dont need to add one more otherwise I need to create new record.

Comment: Could you please explain what your query is supposed to find? What's your end goal with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't have two children with the same name for a given parent, you could do something like this:

```
select count(child.id) from Parent p inner join p.children child
where p.project = 'project' and child.name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')
```

If it returns 3 or more, then a parent with these children already exists.

Comment: There is some problem - child does not have "name" field. it contains 4 fields which make child unique for this parent. I assume I can create such "name" by hash or concatenation. I will try to modify Your solution and implement it. Thank You.

Comment: In your question, child has a name ?!

Comment: in question yes, sorry. but in reality it has 4 fields. I suppose I can just change child.name in (...) AND child.surname in (...)

Comment: No, you can't do that. It wouldn't be correct. You could use concatenation with a specific separator: `and (child.name || '#' || child.surname) in ('name1#surname1', 'name2#surname2', 'name3#surname3')`

Comment: I use even more fast way but still get slow search. I Use query like

`SELECT r FROM Request r WHERE r.profileID = ?1 AND r.caseSensitive=false AND r.useWildCards=false AND r.criteriaHash=-249414680`

Query time: 157

Comment: Add indexes to the table. That's what makes a query fast.

Comment: I think I must search for another way. I need export about 30K entities per minute with duplicate check.
Back to the topic - query not  single problem. Performance slowly decreasing in time without any dependency of table size. Your answer was helpful but my choice of framework seems to be wrong. Thank You.